# How do I know if a package on flathub in official or not?

Tags: linux, fedora, flatpak

I am new to Linux and i recently discovered Flathub. I am currently on Fedora39 and my only perplexity is the nature of the packages available on it. how do I know, for example if this package [image]

is official or not a third party potential malicious one?
is flathub in general a safe place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verified apps on Flathub have a blue checkmark; see [the GIMP](https://flathub.org/en-GB/apps/org.gimp.GIMP) for example. [This means that](https://flathub.org/en-GB/about)

> the app is published on Flathub by its original developer or a third party approved by the developer.

Such apps are as trustworthy as the original developer.

Unverified apps such as [Chrome](https://flathub.org/en-GB/apps/com.google.Chrome) don’t get the checkmark and often have an additional warning; in Chrome’s case:

> NOTE: This wrapper is not verified by, affiliated with, or supported by Google.

Flathub also highlights sandboxing permissions when they could be dangerous; again for Chrome:

> **Potentially unsafe**
>
> User device access; Download folder read/write access; Can access some specific files; User settings; Legacy windowing system

Answer (score 0):

Not at all, who can decide what the "official" build for something is, anyways, for most Free and Open Source projects?